# Print Method in Java with an attached pic

Tags: java

The picture I attached is of the output screen. I’d like the first line to be 30 USD. What to do? Here is my code:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.print("USD");
    double sum = Double.parseDouble (scanner.nextLine ());

    double UsdBgn = sum * 1.7954;
    double UsdEur = sum / (1.95583/1.79549);
    double UsdGbp = sum / (2.53405/1.79549);

    System.out.printf("%.2f BGN\n", UsdBgn);
    System.out.printf("%.2f EUR\n", UsdEur);
    System.out.printf("%.2f GBP\n", UsdGbp);
```

Output Screen:

[image]

Comment: `System.out.println("30 USD");`

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like the user to input only 30 by hand and BGN to be there.

Comment: I suspect the real question is how to erase what is in the console (the USD30, and then print the correct format)

Comment: I can erase the unwanted first line but can't print the format I want.

Comment: If you can erase the first line, why can't you use `System.out.println(sum + " USD");` right after?

Comment: Because the result is                                                                                30
30.0 USD
53.86 BGN
27.54 EUR
21.26 GBP
And I don't want 30 on 2 lines.

Comment: Erase the unwanted first line, didn't you say you could?

Comment: I erased mine and added your suggestion. See:                                        
                                                                                                        
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);

        //System.out.print("USD");
        double sum = Double.parseDouble (scanner.nextLine ());
        System.out.println(sum + " USD");                                                 The result on the output of the console is:                                                30
30.0 USD
53.86 BGN
27.54 EUR
21.26 GBP

Comment: People who answered down explained it's not so easy. You could read if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string concatenation using '`+`' operator to join strings together, by concating a double you implicity call double.ToString function so it should print out fine.

So inserting: 
    `System.out.println(sum+" USD");` after the input statement will printout to the console the value that user inputted.

So it will look something like this:

```
double sum = Double.parseDouble (scanner.nextLine ());
System.out.println(sum+" USD");
```

Sidenote -
You don't have to cast String to Double when using scanner

```
double sum = Double.parseDouble (scanner.nextLine ());
```

can be transformed to :

```
double sum = scanner.nextDouble();
```

Comment: 30
30.0 USD
53.86 BGN
27.54 EUR
21.26 GBP -----> this is the result, but I don't want 30 on the first line.

Comment: The first 30 is your input that you typed in, as far as I know there's no way to disable it, nor do I believe scanner allows to move the cursor so you don't enter a new line.

Comment: @A.A It's possible for it to be [entered as a password](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#readPassword--) and not show up

Comment: You can use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/Console.html readPassword method from Console class but I don't think scanner supports it directly. Additionally you will have to run it from an actual console not from an IDE

Comment: Me too but since we can print before typing (for example: System.out.printf("USD = ");
double sum = Double.parseDouble (scanner.nextLine ());                              I thought printing straigh after typing was also possible.

Comment: I understand you want to move the cursor so it's on the same line after you input but this is not possible with just a Scanner class, there might be some library that could help but that's beyond my knowledge.

Comment: A.A, I always parse integer and double. If we don't do it, see what happens when you should type and then print Integer, Double and String:                         import java.util.Scanner;
public class StackOverFlow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);

        int a = scanner.nextInt();
        double b = scanner.nextDouble ();
        String c = scanner.nextLine ();

        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}           ----> String is skipped!!!

Comment: Indeed that's because nextDouble/nextInt do not capture newline, the reason I suggested it is because in this scenario it's not a problem. Alternatively depending on the context you can use .next() rather nextLine and should solve the issue too :p

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I just always parse so to be sure all will be fine :)